# WordPress plugin won't create custom tables

Tags: plugins, php

I’m making a plugin that uses custom tables.

On my local dev site the tables are being created and everything is working, but when i activate the plugin on a live site the tables aren’t being created.

here’s the code I’m using

```
// activation hook
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'Gripper_Activate', 'activate' ) );

// activation class
class Gripper_Activate {
    /**
     * Class Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        // Activate plugin when new blog is added
        add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', array( $this, 'activate_new_site' ) );
    }
    /**
     * Fired when the plugin is activated.
     *
     * @param boolean $network_wide True if WPMU superadmin uses "Network Deactivate" action, false if WPMU is disabled or plugin is deactivated on an individual blog.
     */
    public static function activate( $network_wide ) {
        if ( function_exists( 'is_multisite' ) && is_multisite() ) {
            if ( $network_wide  ) {
                // Get all blog ids
                $blog_ids = Gripper_Get_Blog_IDs::get_blog_ids();
                foreach ( $blog_ids as $blog_id ) {
                    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
                    self::single_activate();
                }
                restore_current_blog();
            } else {
                self::single_activate();
            }
        } else {
            self::single_activate();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Fired when a new site is activated with a WPMU environment
     *
     * @param int $blog_id ID of the new blog
     */
    public function activate_new_site( $blog_id ) {
        if ( 1 !== did_action( 'wpmu_new_blog' ) ) {
            return;
        }
        switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
        self::single_activate();
        restore_current_blog();
    }
    /**
     * Fired for each blog when the plugin is activated
     */
    private static function single_activate() {
        Gripper_WP_Version_Check::activation_check('3.7');
        Gripper_Create_Tables::create_syn_result_table();
    }
}

// Class to create tables
class Gripper_Create_Tables {
    static $gripper_db_version = '1.0.0';
    public static function create_syn_result_table() {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_syn_result = $wpdb->prefix . "rsg_syn_result";
        if($wpdb->get_var("show tables like '$table_syn_result'") != $table_syn_result){
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_syn_result . " (
                `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                `page_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                `language` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
                `position` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                `gdomain` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
                `keyword` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
                `synonym` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
                `keyword_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                `type` enum('heading','description') DEFAULT NULL,
                `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
            );";
            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
            dbDelta($sql);
            if( !get_option( "gripper_db_version" ) ) {
                add_option( "gripper_db_version", self::$gripper_db_version );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The activation hook is working, because the version check is running, but the tables just aren’t being created on the live server.

Comment: can you confirm that db user that you are connecting with has CREATE TABLE privileges?

Comment: Fixed the issue. An unrelated call to a different database was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`dbDelta()` is picky-- maddeningly picky.

> - You must put each field on its own line in your SQL statement.
> - You must have two spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the    definition of your primary key.
> - You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you    must include at least one KEY.
> - You must not use any apostrophes or backticks around field names.
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table

You have violated at least one of those rules-- the last one--, and I believe the second one as well.